# Enforce Global Namespace in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces, global-namespace

In XAML, a custom namespace can be imported with an `xmlns` directive:

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:GreatStuff"
```

In C#, that namespace can be imported with

```
using GreatStuff;
```

Moreover, evaluation of that namespace based on the global (root) namespace can be enforced as follows:

```
using global::GreatStuff;
```

**How can I enforce evaluation based on the global namespace in XAML?**

---

**Background:**

I am facing the (admittedly slightly obscure) situation that there is such a namespace `global::GreatStuff`, which contains a WPF control class named ... `GreatStuff` (i.e. fully qualified, that's `global::GreatStuff.GreatStuff` in C#). In the same namespace, I want to use that control in a WPF window.

Interestingly, in this constellation, I cannot use the `Name`/`x:Name` attribute on any controls of type `global::GreatStuff.GreatStuff` in my XAML file for the window:

> The type name 'GreatStuff' does not exist in type 'GreatStuff.GreatStuff'. (CS0426)

Note that the very same file compiles fine if I do not specify a `Name`/`x:Name` attribute!

Now, why should the compiler assume that by setting a `Name`/`x:Name` attribute, I am trying to access something called `GreatStuff.GreatStuff.GreatStuff`?

The answer can be found by examining the `.g.cs` file generated from the window XAML file. In that file, the XAML snippet

```
<custom:GreatStuff x:Name="stuff"/>
```

gets compiled to the following C# snippet:

```
internal GreatStuff.GreatStuff stuff;
```

That is, the fully-qualified name is used, but without the explicit global namespace marker.

Of course, as a field in a class in namespace `global::GreatStuff`, all of this is wrapped in

```
namespace GreatStuff {
```

And so, the poor C# compiler cannot help but assume that `stuff` is supposed to be of a type `global::GreatStuff.GreatStuff.GreatStuff`. This could be avoided if in

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:GreatStuff"
```

I could enforce that any mentions of that namespace prefix could be converted while enforcing the global namespace.

*For reasons external to this question, changing the namespace and/or class names is not an option here.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue only occurs when all of the following are true:

1. You have a class with an identical name as the namespace containing it.
2. Within that same namespace, you have a xaml file with an instance of an object that is also declared within that namespace.
3. That specific object instance is given a Name or x:Name attribute.

If you cannot modify anything to make any one of those conditions false, then you are working with some very serious restrictions.

As far as I know, this is a limitation of the xaml compiler, and you will need to contact Microsoft about resolving it. The only other thing I can think of would be to try to work around it with a custom build process that builds xaml, allows you to edit the generated files, then builds the code. That would require some research to figure out how to set up.

Comment: How about sub typing it with another name then reference that sub type in xaml?