# Enforce global namespace in XAML auto generated files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

My problem is distinct from this other question [Enforce Global Namespace in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607193/enforce-global-namespace-in-xaml) in that I don't have a class with the same name as the enclosing namespace, yet I couldn't think of a more appropriate title that would differentiate the two.

If any part of my XAML object's namespace is also the root of another namespace, Visual Studio seems to prefer my XAML object's namespace, which manifests as a compiler error.

Here is an example that shows how *part of* my namespace `WpfApp1.System.Views` clashes with `global::System`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.System.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Amazing content goes here -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There are compilation errors shown in the Errors pane and `obj/System/Views/MainWindow.g.i.cs` shows this with a squiggly red underline under the `System` part of `System.Windows.Window`:

```
namespace WpfApp1.System.Views {
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Obviously my toy example only stops me from having a `System` namespace *anywhere in my hierarchy*, but it also stops me from having any 3rd-party names (like `DevExpress`) if I'm using one of those 3rd-party components in XAML.

Without renaming either my own namespace (or the referenced components' namespaces) can I ask Visual Studio to use `global::` namespaces in its generated XAML code?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but as far as I know such option does not exist.